# Why does PHP's ssh2_auth_pubkey_file require a public key?

Tags: php, ssh, ssh-keys

I can log into a server using only a private key via command line. Why does this PHP function require a public key also?

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($server_address, $port, array('hostkey'=>'ssh-rsa'));
if (!@ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $username, $public_key_path, $private_key_path, $password))
{
  echo '<h3 class="error">Unable to authenticate. Check ssh key pair.</h3>';
  break;
}
echo '<h3 class="success">Authenticated.</h3>';
```

I am working on a personal use test script to check firewall settings and access permissions as I adjust and deploy new servers. I'm mostly just curious as this seems to indicate I am missing some information about how ssh works. But I'm also annoyed that I have to give two paths when it seems I should only need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a direct experience with PHP SSH2 functions. But PHP [`ssh2_auth_pubkey_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-auth-pubkey-file.php) internally calls [`libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile_ex` from libssh2](https://libssh2.org/libssh2_userauth_publickey_fromfile_ex.html), whose documentation says about the `publickey` parameter:

> Path name of the public key file.
> (e.g. `/etc/ssh/hostkey.pub`). **If libssh2 is built against OpenSSL, this option
> can be set to NULL.**

<del>So maybe you can pass `null` in PHP (as PHP builds against OpenSSL).</del> If not, it's only a limitation of PHP SSH2 API. Not a something that comes intrinsically from SSH as such.

---

For the reason why SSH APIes usually allow specifying a separate public key file, when key-pair file (usually not-really-correctly called private key file) is enough, see my answer to:
[Purpose of pubkey parameter of JSch.addIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59661442/850848)

I believe that given the PHP SSH API, the argument is rather useless, as the API does not even allow you to have multiple keys loaded and you have to specify the passphrase upfront anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately PHP does require the parameter be a path to a real file and the file must be a real public key enforced by several assert statements for length and format. Though you did answer my question so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you "log on to a web site," you *always* present the **public** key.

The corresponding private key should be very-securely kept on the server so that it can use it to validate the public keys that are presented.  **Private** keys should never be "out in the wild."

Alternatives exist – often, the server only contains a "signing key" (for self-issued certificates), or it simply relies on the fact that the presented key has been signed by a recognized authority.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also the PHP function asks for both private and public which only slightly alters the question to "Why does it need both?"